# Time recovery - GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio

I read about Time recovery (as an example, the  *Mueller&Muller* algorithm); it is linked to when you should  sample your signal.

I am currently working on a project with GNU Radio and there is some blocks that perform time recovery.

I don't get how those blocks actually perform a time recovery in the digital world because they can't change the sample that the USRP produces... I don't understand how such algorithm can be implemented  on the digital side with out affecting the USRP itself which is the device sampling the signal.

Comment: There are two kinds of sampling going on. The USRP turns a continuous signal into a discrete signal. After matched filtering (implemented in digital backend), the signal is sampled again at specific time instants, to get the transmitted bits. This second sampling is what M&M is about.

Comment: @MBaz so the samp_rate only affect how you sample the already sampled stream of data that come from the USRP? So the samp_rate is a downsampling?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by `samp_rate`. If it is the number you give the USRP, then no, the USRP's sample rate is the rate at which the RF continuous signal is discretized.

Comment: Well you are saying that the USRP sampling rate is constant what ever the samp_rate variable is set @MBaz

Comment: `samp_rate` is a variable. You can use it to specify anything. You can use it to specify the sampling rate of the USPR, or you can use it for something else. You have not specified what that variable is.

Comment: @MathieuL are you aware of what pulse shaping does?

Comment: @MarcusMüller mhm is that the effect cause by the non ideal sampling that we use rectangular window instead of dirac to sample the signal?

Comment: @MBaz sorry if I was unclear, I refer to the typical variable create by default in a flow chart of GNU Radio

Comment: A window, but in useful modulators, that window is not rectangular!

Comment: You must really understand what a pulse shaping filter does, @MathieuL; that's very important for understanding what timing recovery needs to do!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I just read my reference about pulse shaping, a nutshell, it is to respect Nyquist criterion in bandwidth limited channel. So we shape our signal with  a raised cosine to meet the Nyquist's criterion. Time recovering is to sample at the peak of the cosine therefore where the eye is the most open.

Comment: Exactly! Also, note that the conditions for pulse shape filters are that their impulse response = 0 for every full symbol period (except for the t=0 one), which means that at exactly these "peaks" it's ok to demodulate, because the value there only depends on the current symbol. go a little back or forth in time – and the pulse shape of the adjacent symbols are part of what you observe!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40497/discussion-between-mathieul-and-marcus-muller).